# I received below error when converting JSON object having property of json array to a java object

Tags: java, json, jsonb, tomcat9

I received below error when converting JSON object having property of json array to a java object. The error and related files are shown below. Here I use tomcat as the web container.

Error.

```
13-Apr-2021 16:35:24.828 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-118] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [OrderServlet] in context with path [/pos] threw exception
jakarta.json.bind.JsonbException: Internal error: Unexpected char 194 at (line no=2, column no=1, offset=2)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserialize(Unmarshaller.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.deserialize(JsonBinding.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.fromJson(JsonBinding.java:80)
    at lk.ijse.dep.web.api.OrderServlet.doPost(OrderServlet.java:32)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at lk.ijse.dep.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:21)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: jakarta.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 194 at (line no=2, column no=1, offset=2)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.unexpectedChar(JsonTokenizer.java:577)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$ObjectContext.getNextEvent(JsonParserImpl.java:442)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonbRiParser.next(JsonbRiParser.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserializeInternal(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractContainerDeserializer.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Unmarshaller.deserializeItem(Unmarshaller.java:62)
    ... 32 more
```

My related OrderServlet, Order and OrderDetails class are shown below.

OrderServlet Class

```
package lk.ijse.dep.web.api;
import jakarta.json.bind.Jsonb;
import jakarta.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;
import lk.ijse.dep.web.model.ABC;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "OrderServlet",urlPatterns = "/orders")
public class OrderServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
        Order order= jsonb.fromJson(req.getReader(), Order.class);
    }
}
```

Order class

```
package lk.ijse.dep.web.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Order implements Serializable {
    private String orderId;
    private String orderDate;
    private String customerId;
    private ArrayList<OrderDetails> orderDetails;

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(String orderId, String orderDate, String customerId, ArrayList<OrderDetails> orderDetails) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.orderDetails = orderDetails;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public ArrayList<OrderDetails> getOrderDetails() {
        return orderDetails;
    }

    public void setOrderDetails(ArrayList<OrderDetails> orderDetails) {
        this.orderDetails = orderDetails;
    }

}
```

OrderDetails Class

```
package lk.ijse.dep.web.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class OrderDetails  implements Serializable {
    private String orderId;
    private String itemCode;
    private int qty;
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    public OrderDetails() {
    }

    public OrderDetails(String orderId, String itemCode, int qty, BigDecimal unitPrice) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getItemCode() {
        return itemCode;
    }

    public void setItemCode(String itemCode) {
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public BigDecimal getUnitPrice() {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice(BigDecimal unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

}
```

The JSON object I sent is shown below.

```
{
    "orderId": "OD007",
    "orderDate": "2021-01-13",
    "customerId": "C001",
    "orderDetails": [
        {
            "orderId": "OD007",
            "itemCode": "I001",
            "qty": 2,
            "unitPrice": 500
        },
        {
            "orderId": "OD007",
            "itemCode": "I002",
            "qty": 2,
            "unitPrice": 900
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In your servlet you use `ABC.class` instead of `Order.class`.

Comment: Thank you.(It must be corrected as Order.class) Even after adding Order.class give the same error.